# Return Optional<User> instead of Optional<BigDecimal> which is inside

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream, option-type

I am trying to write a stream which return the richest employee.

```
Optional<User> getRichestEmployee() {
    return getUserStream()
        .flatMap(user -> user.getAccounts().stream())
        .map(this::getAccountAmountInPLN)
        .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .findFirst();
}
```

My method `getAccounts()` returns `List<Account>`

My method `getAccountAmountInPLN` looks like this:

```
BigDecimal getAccountAmountInPLN(final Account account) {
    return account
            .getAmount()
            .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(account.getCurrency().rate))
            .round(new MathContext(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
}
```

My problem is, that `getRichestEmployee()` returns `Optional<BigDecimal>`.

I am not able to `return` the richest employee. While running on the stream, I lose access to `User` objects. How to return a User?

Comment: To find *richest* employee *(assuming `User`?)*, wouldn't you have to sum the amounts of all the employees accounts? I see no attempt at getting a total account balance for the employee. Re-think what you're trying to do.

Comment: Can we see your Account class?

Comment: @Andreas you're right. So I have to sum up all the bills for each employee. (I do not know why I did not add it in the question - it results from many of my editions and attempts in this method). @BenjaminUrquhart `@Builder
@Data
public class Account {
    private final AccountType type;
    private final String number;
    private final BigDecimal amount;
    private final Currency currency;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to find richest employee, you need to sum the amounts of the employee's accounts.

Second, to find to employee with the largest summed amount, use [`max(Comparator<? super T> comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-)

Example:

```
Optional<User> getRichestEmployee() {
    return getUserStream()
            .max(Comparator.comparing(this::getEmployeeAmountInPLN));
}

BigDecimal getEmployeeAmountInPLN(final User user) {
    return user.getAccounts()
            .stream()
            .map(this::getAccountAmountInPLN)
            .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
}

BigDecimal getAccountAmountInPLN(final Account account) {
    return account
            .getAmount()
            .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(account.getCurrency().rate))
            .round(new MathContext(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're calculating the wealth of your user by finding an account with the highest amount.

Firstly create an additional method to get an amount from a user:

```
public BigDecimal getUserMaxAmount(User user) {
    return user
            .getAccounts()
            .stream()
            .map(this::getAccountAmountInPLN)
            .max(Comparator.naturalOrder())
            .orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO); //if user has no account I default to 0
}
```

then you can just use it like that:

```
Optional<User> getRichestEmployee() {
    return getUserStream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(this::getUserMaxAmount, Comparator.reverseOrder()))
            .findFirst();
}
```

or even simpler:

```
Optional<User> getRichestEmployee() {
    return getUserStream().max(Comparator.comparing(this::getUserMaxAmount));
}
```

If your intention was to calculate the wealth of user by summing all amounts, you should reduce your stream to a single value by summing amounts:

```
public BigDecimal getUserTotalAmount(User user) { //instead of getUserMaxAmount
    return user
            .getAccounts()
            .stream()
            .map(this::getAccountAmountInPLN)
            .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea and for assuming that I have to count the user's wealth by adding all amounts.

Answer (score -1):

Make your own Comparator and don't map each account to its balance:

```java
Optional<User> getRichestEmployee() {
 return getUserStream()
    .flatMap(user -> user.getAccounts().stream())
    .sorted((a1, a2) -> this.getAccountAmountInPLN(a2).compareTo(this.getAccountAmountInPLN(a1)))
    // Assuming there's a getter for the account owner...
    .map(Account::getOwner) // replace with Account's getter for owner
    .findFirst();
```

Comment: `Account::getOwner` is an entirely new construct from a data perspective and might not be preserved. I mean there is no information in the question which can get you the owner given an account.